# Dynamic facebook app credentials for Laravel 5.1 socialite

Tags: facebook, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-socialite

We are trying to use dynamic facebook app credentials for Laravel 5.1 socialite.

> config/services.php

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => 'xxxx',
    'client_secret' => 'xxxx',
    'redirect' => 'http://example.com/facebook-callback',
],
```

> On my controller file:

```
public function getConnectFacebook()
{
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
}

public function getFacebookCallback()
{
    $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();        
}
```

We tried to overwrite the facebook driver this way:

```
public function getConnectFacebook()
{
     Config::Set("services.facebook.client_id", "dynamic_app_id");
     Config::Set("services.facebook.client_secret", "dynamic_app_secret");
     Config::Set("services.facebook.redirect", "dynamic_app_redirect");        
     return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
}
```

But it was not working. Could you please let me know how we can achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
 return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect()->setTargetUrl('your callback url');
```

Comment: How will you set the client_id and client_secret dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
    private function makeFacebookDriver($domain){
//grab and set your config values from database or array. Don't do Config::Set.
$config['client_id'] = '';//grab fb id based from db based on domain
            $config['client_secret'] = '';//grab fb secret from db based on domain
            $config['redirect'] = 'http://'.$domain.'/fbcallback';
            return  Socialite::buildProvider(\Laravel\Socialite\Two\FacebookProvider::class, $config);
    }
```

then use the function instead of calling  Socialite::driver('Facebook');

```
$fb = $this->makeFacebookDriver('www.test.com');
return $fb->redirect();
```

Comment: How to achieve during call back. I mean it redirects fine and while callback it again fetches the services file for configuration.

Comment: not working  in callback always return unauthorized .do u know how to set callback?

Answer (score 0):

just use it in your controller

```
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\FacebookProvider;
```

config

```
   $config = [
        'client_id'    => '969935-d61celu1qck667krmbgql.apps.googlesercontent.com',
        'client_secret' => 'sHrnnOz3Fmz4',
        'redirect'     => 'http://localhost:8000/api/login/facebook/callback'
    ];
  $user=  Socialite::buildProvider(FacebookProvider::class, $config)->stateless();
  return $user->redirect();
```

stateless in callback

```
$userSocial =$config = [
        'client_id'    => '969d61celu1qck667krmbgql.apps.googlesercontent.com',
        'client_secret' => 'sHrnnO3Fmz4',
        'redirect'     => 'http://localhost:8000/api/login/facebook/callback'
    ];
  $user=Socialite::buildProvider(FacebookProvider::class, $config)- 
>stateless()->user();
```

**api or web.php**

```
Route::get('login/{provider}', 'SocialController@redirect');
Route::get('login/{provider}/callback','SocialController@Callback');
```

Answer (score -2):

You could also do a simple find and replace.

Let's say you have a config file like this

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => '{ID}',
    'client_secret' => '{SECRET}',
    'redirect' => '{REDIRECT}',
],
```

Now within your controller you can do something like this.

```
$fileName = 'path/to/file.php'; 

$configData = file_get_contents($file);

$configData = str_replace('{ID}','dynamic_id',$configData);
$configData = str_replace('{SECRET}','dynamic_secret',$configData);
$configData = str_replace('{REDIRECT}','dynamic_link',$configData);

file_put_contents($file, $configData);
```

That's it, nothing fancier.